# In Java, does the order of InputStream matter?

Tags: java, file, inputstream

I'm currently learning Java and I'm currently trying to understand how the language deals with files.

So here's my question : is there a difference between :

```
BufferedInputStream di1 = new BufferedInputStream(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("finn.txt"))));
```

and

```
DataInputStream di2 = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("jake.txt"))));
```

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: I can't think of any reason you'd want the first one. The second one is useful to add buffering to your `DataInputStream`.

Comment: Yes, order does matter. All implementations you mention (except for `FileInputStream`) read from "underlying input stream", they do not see or care where that "underlying stream" gets the data from, they only care whether or not the underlying stream can hand them the next piece or not.

Comment: The first question to ask is "what type of InputStream do I want to work with" ? If you do not need a `DataInpuStream`, do not use it, otherwise, wrapping the `FileInputstream` in a `BufferedInpuStream` is simply a performance optimization (which may work against you depending on memory, file size, etc...)